# unable to pass boolean value

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a form field/checkbox and am unable to pass the boolean value even though it is selected.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="IsContactValid"
               id=" IsContactValid" 
                  <cfif                        
                        ContactView.GetIsContactValid()>CHECKED
         </cfif>>
that will be transmitted to the receiving form if the box is checked.
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give the check box a value:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="IsContactValid" value="1"
               id=" IsContactValid" 
                  <cfif                        
                        ContactView.GetIsContactValid()>CHECKED
         </cfif>>
```

that will be transmitted to the receiving form if the box is checked.

Comment: `checked="checked"` is more valid for more recent HTML standards.

Comment: I wouldn't say "more valid".  CHECKED by itself is fine for HTML 4.01 and 5.